# jquery Click on Dynamically Created Anchor Tags

Tags: jquery, dynamic, anchor

i am binding my repeater with database values and with anchor tags as below

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <a href='#Roles' id='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"RoleID") %>'>
        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"RoleName") %></a>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

the output of above will be like this

```
abcd--anchor tag with id=1
efgh--anchor tag with id=2
ijkl--anchor tag with id=3
```

on click of the above anchor tag i want to fill the gridview. 
if i detect the anchor click with id it should be something like below, 
but i don't understand how to achieve it through single function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#1').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        Logout();

    });
});
```

any hint how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, add a class to the anchor tags, something like `logoutlink`. Then use jQuery's `live()` function instead of the `click()` function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.logoutlink').live('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        Logout();
    });
});
```

This will attach the event handler to any dynamically created anchor tags that have the `class="logoutlink"` attribute.

Comment: Pass id of anchor to use in function: JQUERY is what i am looking for

Answer (score 0):

if you have a div surrounding your repeater, you can do

```
$('div.surrounding a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    Logout();
};
```

or give them all a class as stated below...

```
$('.classgiventoall')
```

or you can simply do

```
$('#1,#2,#3')
```

is that what you were asking?

Comment: yes, but the id's are generating dynamically "$('#1,#2,#3')" i mean 1,2,3...etc are being fetched from the database, when the anchor tag is clicked i have to pass the id value example 3 and load all the related values in the grid. i got stuck at  anchor tag click detecting and passing the value

Comment: Pass id of anchor to use in function: JQUERY is what i am looking for. any idea please share

Comment: well you can use e.attr('id') to get the id of the element... does that help?